# Prove or disprove the existence of inverse element in $H=\{x=2k+1\}$ of the group $(\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ be a group. Is $H=\{x=2k+1,\;k\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ a subgroup of $(\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$?

---

I need help with the existence of inverse element.

First of all I think $x$ in $H$ is $x\color{red}{\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}}$ i.e. $x=2k+1\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$. Not only $x=2k+1\color{blue}{\in\Bbb{Z}}$. Why? Because of the following:

I need to prove that for all $x\color{red}{\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}}$ there exists a $x^{-1}\color{red}{\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}}$ such that $$x\cdot x^{-1}=x^{-1}\cdot x=e,$$ where $e=1\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$. (The definition of **existence of inverse element**.)

So let $x=2k+1\color{red}{\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}}$. Pick $x^{-1}=\frac{1}{2k+1}\color{red}{\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}}$. The denominator is not $0$ since $k=-1/2\notin\Bbb{Z}$. Then for all $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ we have $$(2k+1)\cdot\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2k+1}\cdot(2k+1)=1=e,$$ so $H$ has an inverse $x^{-1}=1/(2k+1)$.

So my questions are:

1. Is the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ part correct? Or should we use the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ part?
2. Is my inverse correct?

Comment: Is the inverse of $3\in H$ in $H$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you for your comment! Oh no! $3=\frac{1}{2k+1}$ implies $6k+3=1$ so $k=-1/3$ where $k\notin\Bbb{Z}$, so $3$ has NO inverse in $H$. Can we find another expression for the inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if the restriction of $\cdot$ to $H \times H$ is a group operation on $H$.  In this example, the elements of $H$ have multiplicative inverses in $\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ (as you found), but (except for $\pm1$) they are not in $H$, so $H$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Formally, I need to negate the definition of inverse to prove that the negation is true (so the definition does not follow). I think the negation of $$\forall x\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\,\exists x^{-1}\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}(x\cdot x^{-1}=x^{-1}\cdot x=1)$$ is: $$\exists x\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\,\forall x^{-1}\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}(x\cdot x^{-1}\neq x^{-1}\cdot x\vee x\cdot x^{-1}\neq1\vee x^{-1}\cdot x\neq1).$$ Is my negation correct?

Comment: Did you mean $H$ when you wrote $\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: That's my doubt; see question 1 of my post.

Comment: to prove $H$ is not a subgroup, show there are elements in $H$ without inverses in $\color{red}H$

Answer (score 2):

$H$ is a set of integers. Use your knowledge of what inverses of integers look like in $\mathbb{Q}$. They are numbers of the from $\frac{1}{z}$ for z $\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now $\frac{1}{z}$ in general will not be an integer unless $z = 1$ or $z = -1$. Hence if you find any element in $H$ that is not $1$ or $-1$, you know that there is no inverse of that element in $H$, as $H$ only contains integers.

Hence $H$ is not closed under inverses, hence $H$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Thank you! You made it more clear.